# Short story about elderly woman who is refusing her children’s requests that she get rejuvenated

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Rejuvenation can restore your youth but it comes at a cost: you lose your memories. Her children tell her that it’s worth it, they don’t want to lose her, and her husband would want her to. Over the course of the story it becomes clear why she doesn’t want to. Poignant.

Comment: "Time enough for love" by Heinlein has a thread about Lazarus Long wife Dora living out a life without rejuvenating. And I her reason (one life was enough and she'd never match Lazarus anyway) and was pretty sad. But wasn't the focus of more than. 1/4 or so a an 800+ pg book.

Answer (score 5):

This is a story by Nancy Kress from her collection Aliens of Earth (1993) (Arkham House Publishers) and was first published in Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction magazine. The title is "In Memoriam.

Comment: This is very good info for a partial (and first time) answer. I'm happily upvoting

Comment: Thank you! I am searching for my copy and will edit the answer when I find it. I love the book and keep buying copies and giving it away!

Comment: I think the story is "In Memoriam". You can read it at the Internet Archive: https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v12n06_1988-06/page/n113/mode/2up

Comment: Thank you - figured that some one could find it with that information.